# Select Multiple meta_value from WP DB; Single Query

Tags: database, query, mysql, user-meta, users

I am trying to retrieve each user's first and last name, phone, email, and address from the usermeta table. I'm having trouble selecting multiple meta_values, each with its own meta_key, using a single sql query.

I would like the data returned as

First Name, Last Name, Phone, Address, Email
First Name, Last Name, Phone, Address, Email
First Name, Last Name, Phone, Address, Email
First Name, Last Name, Phone, Address, Email

I have access to the actual DB via phpMyAdmin, so I would like help with the mySql query.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to *not* use [`get_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)? (Or, more abstractly, [`get_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_metadata)?)

Comment: @PatJ As an answer please.

Comment: Custom sql queries should be avoided if there is an already native function that will do the job. If a native function does not exist to do the job, and you need to use a custom sql query, you probably need to submit this as a request to include it in future releases of Wordpress

Comment: under slightly different circumstances, get_user_meta() would be the best route to go. Although as stated in the OP, I am looking for the mysql query. I only have direct access to the database.

Answer (score 3):

You can just call `get_user_meta` without specifying a key, and it will return all MetaValues for the user.

```
$userdata = get_user_meta( $userID );
```

You may have to do a mapping for displaytitles of the Metavalue, as they are returned in an `array`, where the `keys` are the databasevalues of your `metakeys`.

For example, you may get

```
$userdata['f711_email_first_name']
```

If you want to display all these elements in a table, create an `array` like this:

```
$displaytitles = array(
    'f711_email_first_name' => 'Email first name',
    ...
);
```

When you loop through `$userdata`, you may output it like this:

```
foreach ( $userdata as $thisdata => $value ) {
    echo $displaytitles[$thisdata] . ': ' . $value[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I was in your shoes, I'd use [`get_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta).

```
// get the users -- I'm ordering them by their username
$args = array( 
    'orderby' => 'login',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
$users = get_users( $args );
foreach( $users as $user ) {
    $user_meta = get_user_meta( $user->ID );
    var_dump( $user_meta ); // to show you what you've got
}
```

This is a **very** simplistic example; in real life you'll probably want to loop through the array that `get_user_meta()` returns, and display things much more nicely than `var_dump()` does.

### References

- [`get_users()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)
- [`get_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)